# Create a class that inherits from textbox and can display calender on click

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, textbox, calendar

I am trying to build a calendar that pop up when you click on textbox (in asp.net);
For this task I build a new class that inherit from text box, and inside the new class constructor I put the calendar instance, but the thing is, when I inctance my new class I only get the textbox control and on click I do not get the calender.
Does anyone have an idea way or how can i fix this? my code is:

```
public class TextBoxCalendar : TextBox
{
public TextBoxCalendar( int id)
{
      this.ID = id.toString();
      initCalender();        
}

    private void initCalender()
    {        
        CalendarExtender ce = new CalendarExtender();
        ce.ID = "calender";
        ce.TargetControlID = this.ID;                                        
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from just initializing the control, you need to add it to the controls collection at some point during the rendering process:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    CalendarExtender ce = new CalendarExtender();
    ce.ID = "calender";
    ce.TargetControlID = this.ID;  
    Controls.Add(ce);

    //render the contents to the screen
    RenderContents(writer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override OnInit method of TextBox and write the initCalender code inside it.

```
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
    CalendarExtender ce = new CalendarExtender();
    ce.ID = "calender";
    ce.TargetControlID = this.ID;     
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Jquery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#default).